# How to show an image on browser in Magento

Tags: database, php-5.4

```
<?php
        $hint = 'dell';

        $sql="SELECT p.`entity_id`, pv.`value` as name, 
                 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pm.`value`) SEPARATOR ', ') as imagesPath
               FROM `catalog_product_entity` as p
               INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` as pv 
                 ON pv.`entity_id` = p.`entity_id` and  pv.`attribute_id` = 71
               LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` as pm 
                 ON pm.`entity_id` = p.`entity_id` and pm.`attribute_id` = 88
               WHERE pv.value LIKE '".$hint."'";

        foreach($readConnection->fetchAll($sql) as $orders) {
?>

<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/product'. $orders["imagesPath"].''; ?>" alt="" />

<?php
    }
?>
```

The output of this code is :-

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento/media/catalog/product/2/_/2.jpg" alt="" />
```

It shows me just the path of the image but i want an image in output on the browser.

Comment: check if image is there on the given path

Comment: i have checked this path is correct and when i past this path onto another tab url it shows me the image it's mean that the path is correct.

Comment: @AfzalKhan Where you put this file or put above code?

Comment: Where are you using this query, in an external file? Is there any `<pre>` code in file?

Comment: No Dear @VinayaMaheshwari I'm not using the pre code in my file I have used an <img> tag  to show the image . I'm trying to make a searchbox in my file .

Comment: Check for the `content-type` header returned by your server. It might be `text/plain` or the like so your browser doesn't render html.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html'); ?>` to the very beginning of your script.